# Why doesn't my display work on my Raspberry Pi 2 with Windows 10 IoT Core?

Tags: display, raspberry-pi, iot, windows-iot-core

I've just installed Windows 10 IoT core in my Raspberry Pi 2, which is brand new. I tried booting it into Raspbian and that all worked fine.

However, under Win10 IoT core, the thing boots but the TV shows just a solid blue screen (the sort you get when there's "no signal"). But there IS a signal because the TV never goes to standby. It never changes from this blue screen.

The Pi is running, I can see it in IoT Core Watcher and I can connect to it with PowerShell, the web interface is working, etc, just no display!

This is very frustrating after all the videos I've seen of people having success with it. We know the TV, cable and display hardware must be OK because it works under Raspbian. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had to change a setting in the config file at `/boot/config.txt` to get my Pi working with my TV.

I don't remember which option I've changed, but probably it was `hdmi_group` (see: [config-txt](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md)).

See also: [Setting up Raspberry Pi](http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/Faqs.htm).

Comment: can you remember what setting it was...?

Comment: Judging by this post https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md it may well have been hdmi_group. I don't have access to my pi at the moment unfortunately.

Comment: This post https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/Faqs.htm would be more relevant but the same setting is used